# Multiple Line Text Align Centre Vertically with Line Height

Tags: flutter, flutter-text

I am currently trying to let the Text apply with certain line height and align the text vertically centre. Since there is no option on TextStyle to vertically align that, I have tried to use the StrutStyle with leading to **approximately** align it to centre. However, after setting the leading, the height for leading and Text with TextStyle height is different.

The demo can check at the [dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/eb039fe71a97b2a63ed2123071c2498f?null_safety=true).

```
    Text(
      'label A',
      style: const TextStyle(
        fontSize: 16.0,
        color: Colors.red,
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
      ),
      strutStyle: StrutStyle(
        fontSize: 16.0,
        leading: (70.0 / 16.0)/2,
        forceStrutHeight: true,
      ),
    ),
```

1. Want to ask if there is any proper way to align it at centre? The Text is **multiple line**.
2. If the leading approach is the recommend method for this case now, is there any calculation can sync the correct height using leading?

Comment: you can wrap text widget in `Center` widget. If the Text widget is in a Row, you can use `MainAxisAlignemnt.center`

Comment: @UjjwalRaijada, thanks for the reply. The main issue is the text is multiple lines and required line-height. I understand I may wrap a Container to do that brutally, but just want to know if there is any other more elegant way.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap With `Align` Widget Which will help you to align wherever you want .

```
 Align (
      alignment : Alignment.topCenter;
    child : Text(
          'label A',
          style: const TextStyle(
            fontSize: 16.0,
            color: Colors.red,
            backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
          ),
          strutStyle: StrutStyle(
            fontSize: 16.0,
            leading: (70.0 / 16.0)/2,
            forceStrutHeight: true,
          ),
        ),
    ),
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! but that may not be fit on multiple line text having a certain line-height